# Why can't the macro "PVPROCPTR"be used in AIX?

Tags: c, macros, aix, kernel-extension

The macro PVPROCPTR(pid)  can convert PID to Process pointer.

so I use it. But there is a error when I make it.

```
1>ld : 0711-317 error : Undefined symbol: pvproc
1>  ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

And the definition of this macro in AIX header file is as follow:

```
extern struct pvproc pvproc[NPROC];     /* the process table, itself      */

/* convert pid to proc pointer  */
#define PVPROCPTR(pid)  (&pvproc[PROCMASK(pid)])
```

So I want to know why can't it be used?

Comment: Since it is an extern, it should be defined somewhere.  The file in which it is defined has not been included in the link

Comment: You probably need to link against system/kernel libraries, using `-l` options.  Which libraries do you currently link?

Comment: The current libraries is as follow: /usr/lib/kernex.exp, libsys.a, libcsys.a; I don't know what lib I should link for the macor;

Answer (score 1):

The question is "why".  So:

pvproc is an internal kernel structure.  If you are making a kernel extension, then what you have might be able to work.  I don't see it exported from any of the *exp files in /usr/lib so it is appears that it is not intended to work from anywhere but from within the kernel itself.

I would expect AIX would provide a kernel service to do what you want rather than a macro.  A kernel service has more stability across different versions of AIX (but it can still change -- just not as often).

Lets step back for a second and ask a bigger question: why do you want the pvproc structure?  (Well... first, answer: is this a kernel extension?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am writing a kernel extension of getting  process info.As u said, some info can get from the AIX kernel service. but the other info can't be accessed. For example, I want to traverse the process list, so I am trying find a process head just like "current" in linux kernel. And actually, I didn't find it now.

Comment: This is going to be a long hard struggle... I would look at getproc (and getproc64) as well as the /proc file system if you are on a later version of AIX. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/getprocs.htm?resultof=%22%67%65%74%70%72%6f%63%73%22%20%22%67%65%74%70%72%6f%63%22%20

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I want to use this macro, what libraries  I should link?

Comment: You might try creating your own export file with pvproc in it.  (Or just hand edit the kernex.exp on your system and use it.)  Use it as an import file.  That will get you past the link issue but it might not load.  If the loader can't find pvproc, I think you have to take another approach... somehow.